# Loading resources from remote path according to screen size and density

Tags: android

My android app supports all screen sizes, but sometimes I need to dynamically load resources from my server, how can I determine (programmatic) which resource to load ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) class to get the screen density and screen width/height in a variety of formats.

You can get the DisplayMetrics by calling `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);`

Just throw that into a switch statement, or cleverly format your resource URLs and requests to make use of the densities.